# Animation subclassed cannot be applied correctly to my view animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

My goal is to show a `subView` with an animation, i have implemented a dedicated class to perform such animation, and i have instantiated from that class and applied it to my subView animation:

```
AnimationClass *ani = [[AnimationClass alloc] init];    
ani.type = AnimationClassTypeTransition;
ani.direction = AnimationClassDirectionMoveUp;

[self.masterView addSubview:self.detailImage withAnimation:ani];
```

Everything goes fine with a smooth transition animation, however, i got the following warning:

```
'UIView' may not respond to 'addSubview:withAnimation:'
```

How can i refactor the code above to solve that warning please? Thanx in advance

**EDIT**
The masterView is a property of `UIView` type. It's declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIView *masterView;
```

And synthesized in the `.m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //choose your animation
[newView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply, actually when i try your snippet, i got no more animation, so the `subView` is shown very fast without an animation, i tried to change the duration value to 4 and 5 seconds, but doesn't get any animation effect, also, i have changed the Transition to `kCATransitionFromBottom`.

Comment: Try this : 

`[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                           forView:newView
                            cache:YES];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:settingsView.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];`

or 

`[UIView transitionWithView:containerView duration:0.5
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp //change to whatever animation you like
        animations:^ { [containerView addSubview:subview]; }
        completion:nil];`

Answer (score 1):

If your code is running without crashing, then you have just forgot the declare your method `addSubview:withAnimation:` of your subclassed `UIView`.I suppose `self.masterView` is of type of subclassed `UIView`, which has a method `addSubview:withAnimation:` but you haven't declared this method in the `.h` file of your subclassed `UIView`.

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply, could you please explain me more? Thanx :)

Comment: What is the type of self.masterView property?

Comment: It can't be UIView. UIView doesn't have a method `addSubview:withAnimation:`. It should be a subclass of UIView that has this method? Where is this method defined? Also show me how do you initialize this `self.masterView` property?

Comment: I have edited my post, the method that contain that snippet of code is implemented on the same file, and gets called when the user click on an image.

Comment: This is the problem - with your property declaration. If your app does not crash, then `self.masterView` is not initialized as an `UIView` but some other class (subclass of `UIView`). Update your code how you initialize `self.masterView`. Also the property attribute should be `retain` not `assign` and you have to release it in the `-dealloc` method.